# NHibernate assocations saved without the many-to-one id

Tags: nhibernate

My root element is saved and all it's assocations, but the id of the reference is not saved.

Entity assocations

MeasureDomain 1 -> * MeasureSubDomains 1 -> * MeasureControls 1 -> * Measure

I have addRange methods on all entities except the last one. Here's an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the sub domains.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The sub domains.
/// </value>
public virtual IList<MeasureSubDomain> SubDomains { get; set; }
/// <summary>
/// Adds the sub domain.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="subDomain">The sub domain.</param>
public virtual void AddSubDomains(IEnumerable<MeasureSubDomain> subDomains)
{
    foreach (var item in subDomains)
        this.SubDomains.Add(item);
}
```

When i call the save method on the session everything is saved, but the reference is lost. See my example:

**MeasureDomain Entry**

```
id  code_1  omschrijving    createdat   createdby   modifiedat  modifiedby  toelichting
75  05  Beveiligingsbeleid  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**MeasureSubDomain Entry**

```
id  code    omschrijving    domein  createdat   createdby   modifiedat  modifiedby  toelichting
204 01  Informatiebeveo     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Directie richting en ondersteuning bieden voor informatiebeveiliging overeenkomstig de bedrijfsmatige eisen en relevante wetten en voorschriften
```

The column domein is NULL and should have the value 75 of my saved MeasureDomain, how can i fix 
this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the SubDomain which Domain it belongs to

```
foreach (var item in subDomains)
{
        item.MeasureDomain = this;
        this.SubDomains.Add(item);
}
session.Update(this);
```

Comment: OMG, this is the 123987 time this happends to me. I totaly forgot to set the domain property it belongs to. Thanks alot! You saved me alot of time, how stupid.